# Multi column search on Yii CGridView

Tags: php, search, yii, cgridview

I have admin page contain CGridView and connected with user database, I need to make search on CGridView work on multi column not just one.. like this:

I need to find user information by phone number OR user name OR email address, is that possible ? and my code is under the image:

[image]

**Code**

User model:
I used OR, but it's not work.. I still search by name only !

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('full_name',$this->full_name,'OR');
    $criteria->compare('full_name',$this->landline,'OR');
    $criteria->compare('full_name',$this->mobile_number,'OR');
    $criteria->compare('email_address',$this->email_address,true);
    $criteria->compare('city',$this->city,true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'id DESC',
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible in Yii

Comment: @bad_boy it is check the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made little mistakes comparing

```
$criteria->compare('full_name', $this->full_name, true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('landline', $this->full_name, true, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('mobile_number', $this->full_name, true, 'OR');
```

First parameter is field in a database and second is what you filled in a form.
You also skipped third parameter which is to allow partial matching.
And the forth parameter needs to be 'OR'

Keep in mind that this is work around, and it can give some headaches later on if you are not careful, because you are storing `landline` and `mobile_phone` into `$model->full_name`.

I would suggest you add another property to User mode, something like `user_info` and than use that property to store input from request and compare it with database.

Example from above will still work, if you wish to improve your code with additional parameter and you can't find your way with it, I'll explain it better, just shout.